# How do I print values in a list that are greater than a certain number along with the row name in R?

Tags: r, loops

I am painfully new to R. I have a list of data, and I wrote a loop to find which values are greater than a certain number:

```
for (i in listname){
    if(i > x)
    print(i)
}
```

I would like for the printed values to also include the row name... how would I go about doing that?
Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strangely, when the item itself is the iterator, the name is lost. If you instead iterate over the number of the item, `print` works as expected:

```
for (i in 1:length(listname)){
    if (listname[i] > x){
        print(listname[i]) # value with name
    } 
}
```

Once you've learned more about R, you will probably want to do this in a "vectorized" way, instead of using a loop:

```
idx <- which(listname > x) # row numbers
listname[idx]              # values with names
```

or with logical subsetting

```
gt_x<-  listname > x       # TRUE or FALSE
listname[gt_x]             # values with names
```

**Example:** Try this with

```
listname <- 1:10
names(listname) <- letters[1:10]
x <- 4
idx <- which(listname > x) # row numbers
listname[idx]              # values with names
# e  f  g  h  i  j 
# 5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It makes sense and I can see why it would work over what I did (all three ways), but when I try any of the methods with my data, I'm still not getting the names.

I created my list by binding vectors together, so there are 3 columns and thousands of rows. If I do the loop you suggested for one of the vectors, it prints out the names. Is there a way to code it so I can apply it to the entire list and still get the names?

Comment: No problem. You might want to make that a separate question. I would do something like `myfun <- function(z) z[which(z > x)]; lapply(DF,myfun)`, assuming you have them in a data.frame... if not `DF <- data.frame(your_mat)` will create it.